# MS ACCESS - Changing column name dynamically in report

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have an MS ACCESS report (1 id column + 6 data columns). I want to change the name of the headers dynamically based on what I have stored in a table (1 columns with 6 rows. Each row telling name of column) NOTE: If can be changed in the main SQL query itself, its great.

Comment: please help me out....

Comment: If you are familiar with VBA, you can write a small piece of code that opens a recordset of your table with the header names and replace the captions of the labels on the report accordingly. Are you able to try that out?

Comment: I do not know VBA. That's the problem. I need to do full automation. Is there any other way to do that??

Comment: Avoiding VBA will make your life more difficult than it needs to be.  Just learn a bit at a time to achieve small tasks

Comment: I do agree with Ashareef and VBlades, it is really more usefull to put your time and energy in learning VBA (even small bits at a time) than looking for workarounds every time (if they even exist).

Answer (score 1):

By "headers", do you mean the Labels on the report?  If so, the easier of the two ways you mentioned is with the additional table solution.  A simple way to do it would be to add a unique ID to your column names table first (how else will you know which column name goes to which label?).  From there you can run something like this when your report loads:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

    lblMyReportLabel_1.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 1")
    lblMyReportLabel_2.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 2")
    lblMyReportLabel_3.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 3")
    lblMyReportLabel_4.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 4")
    lblMyReportLabel_5.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 5")
    lblMyReportLabel_6.Caption = DLookup("[ColumnName]", "[ColumnNames]", "[ID] = 6")

End Sub
```

This code is assuming your your labels are named lblMyReportLabel_?, your column names table is named ColumnNames, the column which actually holds the column names is called ColumnName, and the unique identifier column is called ID.

A slicker way would be to alias the columns in your source query, open a Recordset of the source QueryDef on Report_Load, and update the captions from that, but that is a more complex solution.  If the field names change in the source query, it would mean you would need to rebind each data control in code in addition to updating the label captions.  In the first solution, you would only have to bind the fields to the data controls on the report once at report design time and that's it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my search was for VBA; my mistake.  I'm not sure you can achieve what you want without some coding, in this case.  The solution presented will still work if you are willing to code a tiny bit.  Good luck.

Comment: Good answer, I would probably add a loop to go through the labels in your first example, so that if a new label/column is added, this only needs to be added in the table and not in the code anymore. But since the one asking the question is not used to VBA that might be overkill.

Comment: Agreed, Yohsoog.  But a looping solution would make assumptions about the naming conventions of the controls as well as the ID numbers as being able to be calculated.  The code above can be edited by even a novice to include the proper label names, IDs, etc.  We're on the same page, though.